# Is N-Rooks sampling done with same pattern for each pixel?

Tags: game-physics, raytracing

I am working on a raytracer and I now I implement anti-aliasing, with the N-Rooks method.
I am not sure if the same pattern should be used for each pixel, or I should generate
a new one for each pixel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a new pattern per pixel. In general, the more random the sampling, the less aliasing in the image.